# actual structure size

Tags: c++, alignment, sizeof

How can I know the actual structure size?
using sizeof returns the number of bytes after alignment.
For example :

```
struct s {
               char c;
               int i
}
```

sizeof(s) = 8;
I am interested to get the size of bytes without alignment ,i.e 5

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: maybe turn off aligning ( pragma pack(1) in VS ) and then calculate sizeof(s)

Comment: I agree with Kiril that as it stands the question is not clear, and without any idea of what the OP is trying to achieve, answers are likely to be off target. We need to wait and see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sizeof returns the actual structure size.

The size without padding is a bit meaningless, because the compiler will insert the padding it feels appropriate. Some compilers support pragmas that turn off structure padding, in which case you should use that, but you'll probably get all sorts of fun things happening.

Answer (score 8):

The actual size of structure is size of structure after alignment. I mean `sizeof` return size of structure in the memory. if you want to have an structure that aligned on byte you should tell the compiler to do that. for example something like this:

```
#ifdef _MSVC
#  pragma pack(push)
#  pragma pack(1)
#  define PACKED
#else
#  define PACKED            __attribute((packed))
#endif
struct byte_aligned {
    char c;
    int i;
} PACKED;
#ifdef _MSVC
#  pragma pack(pop)
#endif
```

now `sizeof(byte_aligned)` return 5 and its actually 5 byte in memory

Comment: Same thing, I already mentioned: This will actually pack the structure and we can't be sure, the OP wants this. He/she may just want to retrieve the "real" size, without any padding, without packing.

Comment: The real size is the size that returned by `sizeof`, I mean `sizeof` return a size that I can use like: `pStruct = new an_struct[2]; char* p = (char*) pStruct; p += sizeof(an_struct); ((an_struct*)p)->i = 0;` it should always be valid, so `sizeof` return actual size, you mean intended size, size that I think my structure has, but actual size is size after padding

Comment: That's why I put `real` in quotes :) And I mentioned _`without any padding, without packing`_ . I know what `sizeof` does and what size it gives.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the documentation.

> using sizeof returns the number of bytes after alignment

This is incorrect. `sizeof` returns the number of bytes after **padding**, which is not the same thing.

Thus, if what you want to know is "how much space will my struct take", `sizeof()` is telling you the correct answer.